# Decoding Error - keyNotFound when parsing JSON data

Tags: json, swift

I am using NASA API in my iOS application for getting some images. My response from the server looks like:

```
{
  "date": "2014-02-04T03:30:01", 
  "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00", 
  "resource": {
    "dataset": "LC8_L1T_TOA", 
    "planet": "earth"
  }, 
  "service_version": "v1", 
  "url": "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/api/thumb?thumbid=bc77b079c8ecd07cd668c576c22b83a4&token=a16639b0d38dd68c586c24a6ee5299d9"
}
```

My request url is:

```
https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery/?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY
```

My struct for decoding this response is:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - EarthImages
struct EarthImages: Codable {
    let date: String
    let id: String
    let resource: Resource
    let serviceVersion: String
    let url: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "date"
        case id = "id"
        case resource = "resource"
        case serviceVersion = "service_version"
        case url = "url"
    }
}
```

The problem is - when I am trying to decode my response using the following code

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let earthImages = try JSONDecoder().decode(EarthImages.self, from: data)
                print(earthImages.url)
            }
            catch let error{
                print(error)
            }}

    }.resume()
```

I get in console.

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "date", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"date\", intValue: nil) (\"date\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I used PAW to check if I get correct response, and it works, so the problem more likely is in my code. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in a Xcode playground, of course I had to define my own `Resource` struct.

Comment: Maybe you have some invisible character os something in your code, try to copy/paste the code from here to Xcode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It... looks fine? (Assuming `Resource` is also `Decodable`, but that would be a separate issue). Perhaps the error is actually telling you the truth, you may be attempting to decode a JSON blob that does not have a date value.

You can explicitly see what we're attempting to decode with an added print just before we attempt to decode:

```
if let data = data {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    do {
    ...
```

Then separately, if the date field is not guaranteed to exist in every response, you should make it optional:

```
struct EarthImages: Codable {
    let date: String?
    let id: String
    let resource: Resource
    let serviceVersion: String
    let url: String
}
```

---

Small note, string enums dont need to be redeclared if its exactly the same as the enum case:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case date // "date" is implied
    case id
    case resource
    case serviceVersion = "service_version"
    case url
}
```

Another fun fact: `JSONDecoder` can also convert from snake case automatically without having to define `CodingKeys` if every key is consistent.

So you can also do:

```
struct EarthImages: Codable {
    let date: String
    let id: String
    let resource: Resource
    let serviceVersion: String
    let url: String
}

...

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let earthImages = try decoder.decode(EarthImages.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: Having the CodingKeys as private is fine even if you don't write your own initializer

Comment: @gadu I improved my code with your instructions however I still get the very same error.

Comment: @AlexBrain how sure are you of the data that's being returned? Try adding this before we attempt to decode:
`print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)`

Comment: Exactly what are you answering here? Did you try the original code and got an error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson my original answer made an incorrect assumption so now, as you said, there's no answer, ill clean up this non answer in a bit, want to keep the comment thread alive for now